# Error: No matching function found

Tags: c++, function, class, object, compiler-errors

I am getting an error saying this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Expression::shuntingYard(Expression&)'
```

while the function is declared in the header folder named Expression.h. I can't see what the problem is. I also included all the necessary pre-processor directives.

The following files are included:

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Expression.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Expression expr("2 * (3 + 1)");

    //Set x = 5
    //expr.instantiateVariable('x',5);
    //Set y = 3
    //expr.instantiateVariable('y',3);

    cout << "Answer: " << expr.shuntingYard(expr) << endl;
}
```

### Expression.h

```
#ifndef EXPRESSION_H
#define EXPRESSION_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Expression
{
    private:
        string expression;
    public:
        Expression(string expr);
        ~Expression();
        void instantiateVariable(char name, int value);

        //Function to calculate the postFix string made by the ShuntingYard function
        int evaluate(string, int, int);

        //Function to convert infix expression to postfix
        string shuntingYard(string);

        //Other
        int higherPrecedence(char operator1, char operator2);
        bool IsOperator(char C);
        bool IsOperand(char C);
};

#endif
```

If you can please point out to what I am doing wrong, by receiving this error, I will appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: So you have no such function signature, and you don't provide any automatic conversion from `Expression` to `std::string` either.

Answer (score 3):

The declared function `shuntingYard` takes a `string` by value, not an `Expression` by reference.

As a side-note, adding `operator string()` to `class Expression` would solve your problem:

```
operator string() const
{
    return expression;
}
```

---

**SUPPLAMENTAL**

This is also an option (one which I personally prefer):

```
operator string&() const
{
    return expression;
}
```

In this case, removing the `const` will allow you to change the `expression` member variable outside.

Answer (score 0):

In the class definition you declared function

```
string shuntingYard(string);
```

having a parameter of type `std::string`

However in main you call function with the same name but passing an argument of type `Expression`

```
cout << "Answer: " << expr.shuntingYard(expr) << endl;
```

And there is no conversion function of object of type `Expression` to an object of type `std::string` in the class definition that could be called implicitly.

So the compiler does not see the declaration of the called function and issues the error.

It is the result of the incorrect class design. Function `shuntingYard` have to use data member `string expression;` instead of a string used as argument. That is the function should be declared without the parameter.